# ConnectionQuality is not working in fast network library in Android Fast Networking library

Tags: android, okhttp, android-networking

I am using `Fast Networking Library` in my project in which I have to get response of `ConnectionQuality` but it always get `ConnectionQuality.UNKNOWN`in `response`. I am using [Fast Networking Library](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking). 
Below is my code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btnNetworkQuality;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setIds();
        setListner();   

    }

    private void setIds() {
        try {
            btnNetworkQuality = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNetworkQuality);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setListner() {
        try {
              btnNetworkQuality.setOnClickListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnNetworkQuality:
                    checkBandwidth();
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkBandwidth() {
        Log.e("checkBandwidth() ", " ");

        ConnectionQuality connectionQuality = AndroidNetworking.getCurrentConnectionQuality();
        if(connectionQuality == ConnectionQuality.EXCELLENT) {
            Log.e("Good quality "," ==> ");
            // do something
        } else if (connectionQuality == ConnectionQuality.POOR) {
            Log.e("Poor quality "," ==> ");
        } else if (connectionQuality == ConnectionQuality.UNKNOWN) {
            Log.e("Unnown"," ==> ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the android framework does not provide a way to get the bandwidth of the connection, so I have implemented it a way that whenever you make the network request it calculate the data transfer and time taken. So, At the initial stage, you may get unknown. After some use, you will be able to get the correct connection quality in that session.